# TelnetClient java stream

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, telnet

```
TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
    telnet.connect( "192.168.0.6", 23 );
    PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(telnet.getOutputStream(), true);

    DataInputStream in =
            new DataInputStream(telnet.getInputStream());


        BufferedReader stdIn =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String userInput;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead=in.read(buffer,0,1024)) != -1) { // read from server


            System.out.print(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, "UTF-8"));
            userInput = stdIn.readLine();
            if (userInput != null) {
                out.println(userInput);
                out.flush();
            }


        }
    telnet.disconnect();
```

Hello I have a problem with this program during the connection to the server.
This program should allow me to start a telnet connection to a server and send to it some commands and return me the result of these but when I start the connection some times it return me only the HELLO of the server (Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Service) and not the entire message including LOGIN:
When I send commands the response of these is delayed.
For example i write "DIR" and the response is written only when I press enter two times...
Where I wrong? Please help me.

Comment: You need two separate threads.

Comment: if I write a command and then i read the response why should i need two separate thread?

Comment: it seems works. I LOVE YOU. when I write the complete code I will post it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18542905/262852   for code.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to connect to network services using such protocol (Telnet, FTP ,SSH ..) which are session based protocol and require to keep your connection alive and be interactive with the service , it's recommended to use available Java API instead of reinventing the wheel (only if you are asked to do without a third party library), in your case you can use [Apache Common Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) wich provide a set of helpful features  to connect to servers using many network protocols including Telnet .

Comment: thank you for your reply but i'm just using apache common net. The class TelnetClient is part of it.

Comment: @user3272521 i see, for the problem of double hit enter , try to set `userInput =userInput +"\r\n";` before writing to response to the output stream.